# Bash - reading two files and searching within files

Tags: bash, grep

I have two files, file1 and file2. I want to reach each line from file1, and then search if any of the lines in file2 is present in file1. I am using the following bash script, but it does not seem to be working. What should I change? (I am new to bash scripting).

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line1      
do           
    echo $line1
    while read line2
    do
        if grep -Fxq "line2"  "$1"
        then 
            echo "found"
        fi
    done < "$2"             
done < "$1"
```

Note: Both files are text files.

Comment: Add examples of both files to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus: they're both .txt files.

Comment: Replace `"line2"` by `"$line2"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep -f`

```
grep -f file_with_search_words file_with_content
```

Note however that if `file_with_search_words` contains blank lines everything will be matched. But that can be easily avoided with:

```
grep -f <(sed '/^$/d' file_with_search_words) file_with_content
```

From the man page:

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
      Obtain  patterns  from  FILE, one per line.  If this option is used
      multiple times or is combined with the -e (--regexp) option, search
      for all patterns given.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and
      therefore matches nothing.
```

Comment: And OP had better be sure that `file_with_search_words` doesn't have any blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the command "comm", it compare two sorted files line-by-line

This command show the common lines in file1 and file2

```
comm -12 file1 file2
```

The only problem with this command is that you have to sort the files before, like this:

```
sort file1 > file1sorted
```

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucomm.htm

Answer (score 0):

File 1

```
Line 1
Line 3
Line 6
Line 9
```

File 2

```
Line 3
Line 6
```

```
awk 'NR==FNR{con[$0];next} $0 in con{print $0}' file1 file2
```

will give you

```
Line 3
Line 6
```

that is the content in file 2 which is present in file1.

If you wish to ignore the spaces you can achieve with the below one.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{con[$0];next} !/^$/{$0 in con;print $0}' file1 file2
```